# TinyMce Rails Theme Simple and Theme Advanced in one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have an events.html.haml file. I want the first text area to have a customized plugin, theme:simple.

The next text area, i want it to have everything I specified in my `config/tinymce.yml`

Here's my code:

```
= form_for @event, :url => profile_events_path, :html => {:multipart => true} do |event|
    =render "shared/error_messages", :object => @event
    %label{:for => "title"} Title:
    %br
    = event.text_area :title,:class=>"tinymce", :theme => "simple"
    %br
    %label{:for => "image"} File:
    %br
    = event.file_field :image
    %br
    %label{:for => "date"} Date:
    %br
    = event.text_field :date
    %br
    %label{:for => "location"} Location:
    %br
    = event.text_field :location
    %br
    %label{:for => "description"} Description:
    %br
    = tinymce
    = event.text_area :description,:class => "tinymce"

    %br
    -if current_user.admin
        //%label{:for => "featured"} Feature:
        //%br
        //= event.check_box :featured
        //%br
        %label{:for => "special"} Special/Featured:
        %br
        = event.check_box :special
        %br
    %br
    = submit_tag "Add Event"
```

The problem is, whenever I put the `tinymce theme=>"simple"`  code together with just the `=tinymce`  It turns both text areas as simple. I want the first one to be simple and the other one as advanced.

This is my yml file

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons1_add:
  - forecolor
  - fontselect
  - formatselect
theme_advanced_styles : "Header 1=header1;Header 2=header2;Header 3=header3;Table Row=tableRow1"

theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
  - emotions
  - styleprops
  - preview
  - media
plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen
  - emotions
  - style
  - preview
  - media

apply_source_formatting : true
theme_advanced_more_colors : true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mode](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3amode) `specific_textareas` and [`editor_selector`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aeditor_selector) to adress defined textareas

```
...
mode : "specific_textareas",
editor_selector : "mceEditor"
...
```

Comment: Where should I put these stuffs. Thanks.

Comment: glad to have been able to help